# integrate scandit barcode scanner plugin for cordova app in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

i am trying to integrate the Scandit Barcode scannner plugin to my cordova based application for iOS platform, but am unable to accomplish that. i have tried the following steps:

1) downloaded the SDK for Phonegap/Cordova and extracted it to a folder.
2) using the Cordova CLI, i executed the following command:

```
cordova plugin add <path to the folder>
```

i get the following error when i run that:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Parsing /Users/macuser/Desktop/AppBackup/miniOrangeAuthenticator/platforms/ios/miniOrange Authenticator/config.xml failed:
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/macuser/Desktop/AppBackup/ProjectName/platforms/ios/miniOrange Authenticator/config.xml'
    at Object.config_parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/config_parser.js:28:15)
    at Object.ios_parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/metadata/ios_parser.js:62:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/plugin.js:98:46
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
macmans-MacBook-Air:ProjectName macuser$
```

what may be the reason? is there any other way i canaccomplish it (without CLI) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `miniOrange Authenticator` to `miniOrangeAuthenticator`. I don't think the CLI is a big fan of spaces (I have had problems in the past with them).

Comment: Also, you _can_ add it without the CLI, but it's pretty tricky/fiddly and you have to know what you are doing - so I would not recommend it.

Comment: did not work. i have added two plugins so that does not seem to be the issue. i tried to copy the files, give references in config.xml and then run, and it gave me a host of errors.

Comment: Hmm, it's moaning that config.xml is not available at: `/Users/macuser/Desktop/AppBackup/miniOrangeAuthenticator/platforms/ios/miniOrange Authenticator/`. Can you confirm it is there or not?

Comment: config.xml exists at that location. i have added two plugins in that file as well...

Comment: i have noticed one thing though: directory name is actually miniOrangeAuthenticator and its trying to access miniOrange Authenticator

Comment: Hmm strange. When you done `cordova create`, what did you set your app name to? I'm guessing it was `miniOrange Authenticator` - because in your `platforms/ios` folder, you have a folder labelled `miniOrange Authenticator` by the looks of it?

Comment: i did not have any folder with the space in it. so what i did was to recreate the project and then install the plugin. worked like a charm. don't know how the space got introduced in the first place though...

Comment: Hmm, odd - I tend to also delete the `build` folder found in ./platforms/ios - as this caches some old settings and I have had more problems with it being there whenever I execute `cordova build`. There is a feature for `cordova clean`: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5578